# on recycler view item click new fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have a code for opening an activity on clicking an item in recycler view with shared preferences. I am trying to do the same with fragments.

here is the code with activity.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                switch(position){

                    case 0: {

                        startActivity(new Intent(WeekActivity.this, DayDetail.class));

                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Monday").apply();

                        break;

                    }

                    case 1: {

                        startActivity(new Intent(WeekActivity.this, DayDetail.class));

                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Tuesday").apply();

                        break;

                    }

                    case 2: {

                        startActivity(new Intent(WeekActivity.this, DayDetail.class));

                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Wednesday").apply();

                        break;

                    }

                    case 3: {

                        startActivity(new Intent(WeekActivity.this, DayDetail.class));

                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Thursday").apply();

                        break;

                    }

                    case 4: {

                        startActivity(new Intent(WeekActivity.this, DayDetail.class));

                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Friday").apply();

                        break;

                    }

                    case 5: {

                        startActivity(new Intent(WeekActivity.this, DayDetail.class));

                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Saturday").apply();

                        break;

                    }

                    default:break;
                }

            }

        });
```

I have tried doing it in fragments

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (position) {

                    case 0: {

                        selectedFragment = Timetable.newInstance();

                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Monday").apply();

                        break;

                    }

                    case 1: {

                        selectedFragment = Timetable.newInstance();

                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Tuesday").apply();

                        break;

                    }

                    case 2: {

                        selectedFragment = Timetable.newInstance();

                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Wednesday").apply();

                        break;

                    }

                    case 3: {

                        selectedFragment = Timetable.newInstance();

                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Thursday").apply();

                        break;

                    }

                    case 4: {

                        selectedFragment = Timetable.newInstance();
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Friday").apply();

                        break;

                    }

                    case 5: {

                        selectedFragment = Timetable.newInstance();
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Saturday").apply();

                        break;

                    }

                    default:
                        break;

                }
                FragmentTransaction transaction = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.rel_layout, selectedFragment);
                transaction.commit();


            }

        });
```

Where did i go wrong? What changes should i make? I get no errors. At the same time nothing happens. Help me out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
case 0: {
         loadFragment(fragment);// method to load a fragment i.e
                               //(loadFragment(new MyFragment())

         sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SEL_DAY, "Monday").apply();
         break;
        }
```

Then create the loadFragment function like:

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // create a FragmentManager
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    // create a FragmentTransaction to begin the transaction and replace the Fragment
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    // replace the FrameLayout with new Fragment
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.YOUR_REPLACEMENT_LAYOUT, fragment);
    // save the changes
    fragmentTransaction.commit(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that helped:)

Comment: I am glad i helped you. Please accept my answer if is the right one. Have a great day